# Why is Sextus Empiricus not self-contradicting and where can I read about his works?

Tags: existence, existentialism, skepticism, buddhism

Firstly, Sextus states: "By way of preface let us say that on none of the matters to be discussed do we affirm that things certainly are just as we say they are: rather, we report descriptively on each item according to how it appears to us at the time,” (PH 1.4).
Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/philosophy/comments/9fjyia/some_further_rough_and_loose_notes_on_pyrrho_or/

Isn't he making a determination that "we report descriptively", or does he say this with his judgment suspended about whether or not it's true or false?

I don't think I have a very good grasp on this philosophy because I feel as though I am so fixated on determining weather things are true or false that it is corrupting my mind. I really like his basic idea that the attempt is to reach tranquility by suspending judement (in certain areas?), I would really like to know.

Anywhere I can read about his translations without the commentary of a contemporary scholar would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: are you deliberately misunderstanding the phrase? idt there is anything self contradictory about saying "i'm not sure". i seem fairly able to suspend judgment, anyway. maybe it would help if you included reference to a descripton where SE does not seem to have suspended judgment as to it certainly being the case

Comment: @halp you are asserting (i.e. your sure) that "i'm not sure" so your both sure and not sure

Comment: this again! are you deliberately finding as many infinte regresses as possible to puzzle over? afaik, it's a pseudo contradiction. maybe you should ask "is SE sure that he lacks certainty in his descriptions"

Comment: @halp I have no clue anymore, I'm hoping someone can help

Comment: ok i'll add an answer. thanks for not biting me

Comment: @FaserPye http://www.sciacchitano.it/pensatori%20epistemici/scettici/outlines%20of%20pyrronism.pdf translates "Sextus Empiricus: Outlines of Pyrronism".

Answer (score 0):

> some meta-sentences of this type can lead to paradoxes. "This is a
> sentence." can be considered to be a self-referential meta-sentence
> which is obviously true. However "This sentence is false" is a
> meta-sentence which leads to a self-referential paradox.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-reference

So self reference need not be problematic, it seems.

- I doubt everything

You can doubt that too or, alternatively, construct a belief that you doubt everything except that you doubt things. It seems fairly straight-forward?

---

This reminds of empiricism and the charge of it being self refuting, by e.g. Russell

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2018321

Of course it isn't logically self refuting, but it is *weakened* by self reference.

---

In what way is Sextus Empiricus weakened by the claim that he might be certain that he is unsure of the world? Not in any meaingful way, I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually read the book, which I've heard of, but not had the time to peruse?

*Sextus Empericus* is (was?) a big name, just a few thousand suns ago, had the good sense, or was it sheer luck?, to record for posterity Pyrrho's sum-up of philosophy, as she is practiced.

I suppose it all boils down to some combo of *isms*.